# desktop dynamic path & pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with the following code.

It opens a file saved on desktop of the user (that keeps changing so need help, how to refer the desktop of the user in question)

Also need help with creation of two pivot tables saved on new worksheets,

Thanks

```
Sub CFilter()

' open Monthly report workbook saved on desktop of the user (changes everytime - need help to get to select desktop path)
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\**xxxxx**\Desktop\Monthly_Report.xlsx"

' copy the only sheet saved in Monthly report workbook

Sheets(1).Copy

' Activate Workbook Macro (this contains this macro) & paste the sheet (need code for that)
Workbooks("Macro.xlsm").Paste

' Following code separate the contents of column E and separate the names separated by comma to separate columns starting column L

    Dim N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    For i = 1 To N
        ary = Split(wf.Trim(Cells(i, "E").Text), ",")
        k = 2
        For j = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            Cells(i, k).Value = ary(j)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i



' need code here that create a pivot in another worksheet and only include rows from existing worksheet where column L is blank (need help)
' need code here that create a pivot in another worksheet and only include rows from existing worksheet where column K is blank (need help)


End Sub`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You've asked two very separate questions in one. You'll receive more help with a more clearly defined question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the path of the currently logged in user's desktop:

`Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Monthly_Report.xlsx"`

Comment: Many thanks. Can you please also help in creating pivots & opening Macro workbook !